# Setting one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

How to properly set the one-to-one relationship in Entity Framework's code-first with fluent API?

The root model is the `Project` class. Every project contains exactly one offer. It might also optionally contain one customer order.

The purpose of the historical models is to contain snapshots of the respective non-historical rows (when a `Project` is added, a new `Project` is created and than copied to a new `ProjectHistorical` class, if it is edited, a new `ProjectHistorical` class is created filled with data of the edited `Project`).
The historical objects should be `AutoMapper` friendly. You can consider historical models as a silly, trivial and naive workaround for the absence of temporal databases support in the database engine.

With this configuration, I experience the following difficulties:

1. `CustomerOrders` and `Offers` tables and their historical
   counterparts have a `Project_Id` column generated. I have found no way
   how to force the use of the `Id` primary key or the commented
   `ProjectId` properties (I prefer the use of the commented `ProjectId` properties).
2. `ProjectHistoricals` table has
   `CustomerOrder_Id` and `Offer_Id` columns generated. I have found no way
   how to force the use of the `Id` column (please note, that the `Id`
   column is not a primary key on historical tables) or the commented
   `CustomerOrderId` and `OfferId` columns (on both `Project` and
   `ProjectHistorical` classes; I prefer the use of the commented `CustomerOrderId` and `OfferId` columns).

I have tried to search a lot and tried even more things but nothing worked as (I would have been) expected.

I have the following models:

```
public class Project
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  // public virtual int OfferId { get; set; }
  public virtual Offer Offer { get; set; }
  // public virtual int? CustomerOrderId { get; set; }
  public virtual CustomerOrder CustomerOrder { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectHistorical
{
  public virtual int LogId { get; set; }
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  // public virtual int OfferId { get; set; }
  public virtual Offer Offer { get; set; }
  // public virtual int? CustomerOrderId { get; set; }
  public virtual CustomerOrder CustomerOrder { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerOrder 
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  // public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
  public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerOrderHistorical
{
  public virtual int LogId { get; set; }
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  // public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
  public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class Offer
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  // public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
  public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class OfferHistorical
{
  public virtual int LogId { get; set; }
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  // public virtual int ProjectId { get; set; }
  public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

And the following fluent api (the primary key must be always named `Id` as all models implements a shared interface which is than consumed by generic parts of the application):

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IdKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyAssociationMultiplicityConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PrimaryKeyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToOneConstraintIntroductionConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<TypeNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<AssociationInverseDiscoveryConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerOrder>().HasKey(t => t.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerOrderHistorical>().HasKey(t => t.LogId);
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerOrderHistorical>().HasRequired(t => t.Project);

modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>().HasKey(t => t.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<OfferHistorical>().HasKey(t => t.LogId);
modelBuilder.Entity<OfferHistorical>().HasRequired(t => t.Project);

modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasKey(t => t.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasRequired(t => t.Offer).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.Project);
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOptional(t => t.CustomerOrder).WithRequired(t => t.Project);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectHistorical>().HasKey(t => t.LogId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectHistorical>().HasRequired(t => t.Offer);
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectHistorical>().HasOptional(t => t.CustomerOrder);
```

This is how the model is compiled to the database by the Entity Framework:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.CustomerOrderHistoricals",
            c => new
                {
                    LogId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Project_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.LogId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Projects", t => t.Project_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Project_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Projects",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.CustomerOrders",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Project_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Projects", t => t.Project_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Project_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Offers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Project_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Projects", t => t.Project_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Project_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.OfferHistoricals",
            c => new
                {
                    LogId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Project_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.LogId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Projects", t => t.Project_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Project_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ProjectHistoricals",
            c => new
                {
                    LogId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CustomerOrder_Id = c.Int(),
                    Offer_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.LogId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.CustomerOrders", t => t.CustomerOrder_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Offers", t => t.Offer_Id)
            .Index(t => t.CustomerOrder_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Offer_Id);
```

Comment: Is your data model correct? A one to one relationship generally implies that the two tables should be consolidated into one table.

Comment: I am aware that this should be the same from the theory perspective. However, from the business perspective, Project, Offer and CustomerOrder is a distinct thing. You can imagine that the Project is a folder which contains several documents. Another imagination is that the Project is a workflow and the existence of other models says at which step you are in the process (First, you create an offer to a customer, than you receive an order from the customer, next you ...).